# Apache Curator NPE in JsonInstanceSerializer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-curator

I am facing a strange NPE when starting Apache Curator's `ServiceProvider`. This happens intermittently on the servers, but I was not able to reproduce the error locally, that's why it's so difficult to know what's the problem.

Here's the code:

```
CuratorFramework curatorFramework = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zookeeperConnectString, new RetryNTimes(5, 1000));
curatorFramework.start();
ServiceDiscovery<Void> serviceDiscovery = ServiceDiscoveryBuilder.builder(Void.class).basePath(ZK_BASE_PATH).client(curatorFramework).build();
serviceDiscovery.start();
ServiceProvider<Void> serviceProvider = serviceDiscovery.serviceProviderBuilder().serviceName(ZK_SERVICE_NAME).build();
serviceProvider.start();
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonParser(JsonFactory.java:604)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1973)
at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.JsonInstanceSerializer.deserialize(JsonInstanceSerializer.java:50)
at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceCacheImpl.addInstance(ServiceCacheImpl.java:193)
at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceCacheImpl.start(ServiceCacheImpl.java:96)
at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceProviderImpl.start(ServiceProviderImpl.java:67)
```

What is happening is that in `ServiceCacheImpl#addInstance` a call to `childData.getData()` is returning null, and passing it to be deserialized, what obviously causes the NPE.

I'm using Apache Curator version 2.11.0.

Has anyone else faced the same issue?
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest building a test case and reporting the problem here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CURATOR