# Apache Curator NPE on serviceProvider.start()

Tags: java, apache, service-discovery, apache-curator

I'm using Apache Curator discovery version 4.0.0 and getting this NPE on ConcurrentHashMap.putVal() on starting the service provider for getting a service instance. (kind of like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007102/apache-curator-npe-in-jsoninstanceserializer/) but not on JsonInstanceSerializer).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1535) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceCacheImpl.addInstance(ServiceCacheImpl.java:196) ~[curator-x-discovery-4.0.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceCacheImpl.start(ServiceCacheImpl.java:96) ~[curator-x-discovery-4.0.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceProviderImpl.start(ServiceProviderImpl.java:75) ~[curator-x-discovery-4.0.0.jar:?]
```

My code looks like this.

```
client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("localhost:2181", new  ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3));
client.start();
serviceDiscovery = ServiceDiscoveryBuilder.builder(ServiceRecord.class).client(client).basePath("/discovery/services/").serializer(serializer).build();
serviceDiscovery.start();
serviceProvider = serviceDiscovery.serviceProviderBuilder().serviceName(serviceName).build();
serviceProvider.start();
```

Service Record class is a POJO that looks like this

```
@JsonRootName(value = "serviceRecord")
public class ServiceRecord implements Serializable {
    private String serviceName;
    private String scheme;
    private String host;
    private Integer port;
    // getter and setters
}
```

Comment: could you share your ServiceRecord class code and the data you have in zookeeper?

Comment: It is beginning to look like this has something to do with the service not being registered in Zookeeper. As soon as I put some data in zookeeper this NPE went away. While this is solved for me for now, I think Curator should give better info than an NPE in such a situation. Have filed a JIRA with the Curator team for this. https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CURATOR/issues/CURATOR-453